# JPA lazy fetch not working and throwing LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

i am a new bee to spring data JPA, so i was trying to make something out of it, so that i can know about fetching Modes, but it's throwing a exception, Please make a look at the code.

```
public class State {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<Constituency> constituencies ;

  public void fetchLazyCollection() {
    getConstituencies().size();
  }
}

public class Constituency {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
  State state;
}
```

So, as you can see there are two classes **State** and **Constituency** and from **State** to **Constituency** one-to-many mapping exists and vice versa there is many-to-one.
Please let me know if i have made any stupid mistake here.

```
@Test
public void delhiShouldHaveTwoConstituency(){
  State delhi = new State();
  delhi.setName("New Delhi");

  Constituency northWest = new Constituency();
  northWest.setName("North West");
  northWest.setState(delhi);

  Constituency southDelhi = new Constituency();
  southDelhi.setName("South Delhi");
  southDelhi.setState(delhi);

  Set<Constituency> constituencies = new HashSet<Constituency>();
  constituencies.add(northWest);
  constituencies.add(southDelhi);

  delhi.setConstituencies(constituencies);

  stateRepository.save(delhi);

  List<State> states= stateRepository.findByName("New Delhi");
  states.get(0).fetchLazyCollection();
  assertThat(delhi.getConstituencies().size(), is(2));
}
```

Now, i have a test which is saving a state with two of its constituencies and then i am trying to retrieve them again using :

```
List<State> states= stateRepository.findByName("New Delhi");
```

According to my understanding, i am assuming as this statement will execute, **constituencies** in **State** won't get initialize until next statement executes which is to invoke **fetchLazyCollection** but as **fetchLazyCollection** invokes it's throwing exception of

**could not initialize Proxy - No Session**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.prateekj.model.State.constituencies, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:187)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:138)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:156)
at com.prateekj.model.State.fetchLazyCollection(State.java:35)
at com.prateekj.repositories.StateRepositoryTest.shouldDoIt(StateRepositoryTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
```

as i am assuming, each unit tests in java maintain its own session of interaction with database, may be i am wrong, can anyone please tell me what wrong i have done here ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get the `LazyInitializationException` because after you get out of the `stateRepository.findByName("New Delhi")`, the Hibernate `Session` gets closed, and you are not able to fetch additional associations outside of a running Hibernate `Session`.

Adding `@Transactional` to your test will fix this issue and you won't have to call:

```
states.get(0).fetchLazyCollection();
```

It's best to fetch the lazy associations you need in the original entity query:

```
select s 
from State s 
left join fetch s.constituencies 
where s.name = :stateName
```

Comment: thanks bro, it worked, a little doubt about it, as you said findByName was the method responsible to open/close session, so on the behalf of your statement, i made a StateService object having @Transactional at Class level, it has a method to fetchWithCollection inside whose i am retrieving State and its collection which is in single transaction now,and i am calling this method of service from my test, but it didn't work and same exception occur this time too, Isn't it a single Transaction now ?

Comment: Yes it should. Add your new code to your questions to be verified.

Comment: `
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class StateService {
      @Autowired
      private StateRepository stateRepository;    

      public List<State> getStateWithCollection(String name){
        List<State> states = stateRepository.findByName(name);
        for (State state : states) {
          state.fetchLazyCollection();
        }
        return states;
      }
    }

`
this is the service that i was talking about.

Comment: `    stateRepository.save(delhi);

    List<State> states= stateService.getStateWithCollection("New Delhi");
    assertThat(states.get(0).getConstituencies().size(), is(2));
`
and the part of the test that is interacting with DB is here.

sorry, couldn't make the code to be formatted in the comment section.

Comment: Check that Spring is aware of your transaction annotations: tx:annotation-driven.

Comment: Awesome Bro, It worked again, could you please tell me ,what does this thing actually doing ?
and the one other thing, why it worked when i didn't have this thing and you told me to put the @Transactional on my Test,

Comment: It's already told in the Spring transaction management docs. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading works in persistence context. When your transaction has finished, you can't perform lazy fetch. You can extend your transaction scope, so you can fetch collection within transaction, or create query which will return collection for you. Another way is to manually fetch collection in one of your stareRepository methods, for example `List<State> states = stateRepository.findByNameAndFetchCollection("New Delhi");`, where transaction should be still active.

Answer (score 1):

set lazy flag true to your collection mapping as following

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you fetch lazy collection outside of transaction (session). So you have got two ways:

- Fetch your collection in same session/transaction that loads entity
- Set hibernate property (for SessionFactory) which enables non transactional loading of lazies:

  <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>